# How to get aggregate packet information using a tool like tcpdump

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I'd like to analyze packets in one of my VMs to see where how the network traffic is flowing. I found tcpdump which seems to be able to capture the packets. However, I'd like to find a way to aggregate this information in a way similar to the `top` command which does information aggregation for processes on a host.

Specifically, I'd like to know how many requests are going to two specific hosts, how much data is being sent to them and how much data is being received by them.

I've used the following command to get the raw information: `tcpdump -i eth0 -v host firehose-mainnet-server.default.svc.cluster.local or host rpc-node-proxy-service.default.svc.cluster.local` but I haven't been able to figure out how to get a summary of the information.

Comment: You may be interested in [iptraf](https://github.com/iptraf-ng/iptraf-ng/) or [iftop](https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/), both of which may already be packaged for your distribution.

Comment: Ah, iftop is exactly what I was looking for! If you want to submit that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [iftop](https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) tool does what you want. From the project description:

> `iftop` does for network usage what `top(1)` does for CPU usage. It listens to network traffic on a named interface and displays a table of current bandwidth usage by pairs of hosts.